# Binding files selected with InputFile in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm trying to data bind some user-selected files in the Blazor `InputFile` component, specifically the `AssociatedFiles` property of each `ToDoItem`. This is not working because the `AssociatedFiles` is always `null`.

This is my razor component:

```
@page "/todo"

@using BlazorPlayground.Data

<h3>Todo List</h3>
Total items: @todos.Count()
<br />
Done: @todos.Count(x => x.IsDone) out of @todos.Count()
<br />
Not Done: @todos.Count(x => !x.IsDone) out of @todos.Count()
<br />

<ul>
    @foreach (var todo in todos)
    {
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" @bind="todo.IsDone" />
            <input @bind="todo.Title" />
            <input type="datetime-local" @bind="todo.DateAdded" />
            <InputFile OnChange="@OnFileSelected" @bind-value="todo.AssociatedFiles" multiple  />
        </li>
    }
</ul>


<input placeholder="Write something to do..." @bind="newTodo" />
<button @onclick="AddTodo">Add Todo Item</button>

@code {
    private IList<TodoItem> todos = new List<TodoItem>();
    private string newTodo;

    private void AddTodo()
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newTodo))
        {
            todos.Add(new TodoItem(newTodo));
            newTodo = "";
        }
    }

    private void OnFileSelected(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

This is my `ToDoItem` class:

```
namespace BlazorPlayground.Data
{
    public class TodoItem
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public bool IsDone { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
        public IReadOnlyList<IBrowserFile> AssociatedFiles {get; set;}

        public TodoItem(string title)
        {
            this.Title = title;
            this.IsDone = false;
            this.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, you may have noticed that this is an extension of the [Blazor todo list app tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/build-a-blazor-app?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Never done that before, but I guess this should work...

```
<InputFile OnChange="@((InputFileChangeEventArgs args) => OnFileSelected(args, todo))" multiple  />
```

Get the selected files, and add them to the `AssociatedFiles` field
of the current `TodoItem` object

```
private void OnFileSelected (InputFileChangeEventArgs e, TodoItem todo)
{
    var selectedFiles = e.GetMultipleFiles();
    todo.AssociatedFiles = selectedFiles;
    this.StateHasChanged();
}
```

### UPDATE

> I'm quite new to web development and I didn't know that you could pass anonymous functions to the OnChange attribute there.

It's a lambda expression...

> I thought you were supposed to enter the name of a method there.

The InputFile component exposes an EventCallback property like this:

[Parameter]
public EventCallback OnChange { get; set; }

Usually you assign the name of your event handler to the property attribute like the following:

```
<InputFile OnChange="OnInputFileChange" multiple />
```

And use it like this:

```
private void OnInputFileChange (InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
     selectedFiles = e.GetMultipleFiles();
     message = $"{selectedFiles.Count} file(s) selected";
     this.StateHasChanged();
}
```

You may use a lambda expression as the value of the OnChange attribute, as done below... but in that case it's your responsibility to pass the `InputFileChangeEventArgs` argument to your event handler (`OnInputFileChange`)

```
<InputFile OnChange="@((InputFileChangeEventArgs args) => 
                                   OnInputFileChange(args))" multiple  />
```

This of course is over skill and really superfluous. But if you want to pass a second parameter to your event handler, as in the case of your question, this approach is the correct one.

Comment: Thanks, that works! I donated to the charity linked on your profile. I'm quite new to web development and I didn't know that you could pass anonymous functions to the `OnChange` attribute there. I thought you were supposed to enter the name of a method there. So what is going on here? In particular, how did you know that you can pass an anonymous function to `OnChange`? I would like to fill the gaps in my knowledge.

Comment: Also, you said that you had "never done that before". Am I doing it in an atypical way? How would you have done it?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I've posted a new answer in response. Please copy the content as I'm soon going to delete it. Let me know that you've copied it... Thanks for the donations

Comment: I've literally just copied it. Feels like a waste to delete it, since I'm sure others could benefit from it too. Maybe you could integrate some of it into this answer?

Comment: I've given your expanded answer some thought. My understanding is that this works because `InputFile` is a Razor component that exposes `OnChange` using the `Parameter` attribute as you described. So this means that I could create my own component, say `InputNuke.razor`, give it a parameter `OnNuclearExplosion` and pass things into it, right? Still getting my head around the idea of using a Razor component like an HTML tag.

Comment: See my second answer. Please let me know that you've copied its content as I'm going to delete it.

Comment: This is awesome, working for me too. I need to pass 2nd parameter to when I select a file and this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks for sharing your knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related with foreach. Cuz when you use foreach it added additional prefix, that can be problem why your model can't binded

So I recommend your replace foreach on for and checkout again

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "additional prefix". Would you mind clarifying?

Comment: It's mean what when your model build in html markup, it look like this 
when you use foreach 
<input id="test" name="p_test" value="test">
when you use for
<input id="test" name="test" value="test">

And when you do submit model look on name in html markup and name in model and bind it. But how you can see name in html markup when use foreach look different from name in model.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with initializing `AssociatedFiles` property in the constructor?

```
namespace BlazorPlayground.Data
{
    public class TodoItem
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public bool IsDone { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
        public IReadOnlyList<IBrowserFile> AssociatedFiles {get; set;}

        public TodoItem(string title)
        {
            this.Title = title;
            this.IsDone = false;
            this.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
            this.AssociatedFiles = new(); // initialize this collection
        }
    }
}
```